# normal subgroups of Alternating group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Klein's $4$ group, $\{1\}$ and $A_4$ are three normal subgroups of $A_4$. I want to know about any other normal subgroups of $A_4$. Do these exist?

Comment: Have you tried writing down all the elements and their conjugacy classes? There are only 12 elements, so this is *very* do-able.

Answer (score 3):

Every normal subgroup of $A_4$ consists of families of conjugacy classes.

The conjugacy classes of $A_4$ are:

- $\{1\}$ which has size $1$
- $\{(1\ 2)(3 \ 4),(1\ 3)(2\ 4),(1\ 4)(2\ 3)\}$ which has size $3$
- $\{(123),(243),(134),(142)\}$ which has size $4$
- $\{(132),(234),(143),(124)\}$ which has size $4$

It is also $A_4=4!/2=12$, hence a subgroup has order one of $\{1,2,3,4,6,12\}$.

We can make a normal subgroup of order $1$, the $\{1\}$.

We can't make a normal subgroup of order $2$ since the sizes of some conjugacy classes can't add up to $2$.

We can't make a normal subgroup of order $3$ since the sizes of some conjugacy classes can't add up to $3$ (every subgroup must contain the conjugacy class of $1$).

There is one way to make a normal subgroup of order $4$ by taking $\{1\}\cup \{(1\ 2)(3 \ 4),(1\ 3)(2\ 4),(1\ 4)(2\ 3)\}$ and this is $V$.

We can't make a normal subgroup of order $6$ since the sizes of some conjugacy classes can't add up to $6$.

If a subgroup has order $12$ then it is $A_4$.

Answer (score 1):

Digging a little deeper, the class equation is $1+3+4+4$.  To be normal a subgroup *has* to be a union of conjugacy classes.  From this, and Lagrange, we can see that there are no more normal subgroups.

(Notice that we can see there is no subgroup of order six, because if there were it would be normal (index two).  This provides the smallest group with a counterexample to the converse of Lagrange.)